# How to catch a solidity event from Java

Tags: solidity, events, web3j, android

I am trying to make a decentralized android application. It is an online two player Tic-Tac-Toe game.  I have implemented the back-end with solidity and  a part of the front-end in android studio. More specifically, I got a wrapper class for my contract using solc and web3j, then included it in the android studio project. So I can call different functions of this wrapper class. Right now, a user can create an account and log in and create a game with this front-end. When a second player joins a created game, my contract emits an event to inform the creator that some player has joined the game. Besides, during a game, whenever a player makes a move, an event is emitted to let the other player know.

Now, the difficulty is that I don't know how to catch this event using Java. I have searched a lot about this, but did not find anything useful. Could anybody please explain how to do this or provide a link containing some example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `events` methods exposed in the generated java wrappers.

### Generate the Java wrappers

There are multiple ways to generate the wrappers like using the [web3j-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-gradle-plugin), [web3j-maven-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-maven-plugin), [web3j-cli](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-cli)...

For the `web3j-gradle-plugin`, you should add the following line to your `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
  id "org.web3j" version "4.8.4"
}
```

Then, put a solidity file containing some events under the `src/main/solidity` directory and run the `generateContractWrappers` Gradle task.

Now that you have the wrappers, you can either `deploy` the smart contract or `load` it.

Let's move on to how you can use them to get the events.

### Use the wrappers to listen to events

If you check the generated wrappers, you will find two kinds of methods for each event:

- `get<event_name>Events(TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt)` : This one can be used to fetch an event that was emitted in a certain transaction via providing its `TransactionReceipt`.
- `<event_name>EventFlowable(...)` : And there are two overloads of this one, one that takes an `org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.EthFilter` and another one that takes couple `org.web3j.protocol.core.DefaultBlockParameter`.

If you choose the first one, then you will be able to fetch only the events that occurred in that specific transaction and will get them directly as a `List< <event_name>EventResponse >` containing the events.

For the latter, it will return a `Flowable< <event_name>EventResponse >`. You can use it to actually subscribe to the events, keep listening to them and also set callbacks same way you do with `io.reactivex.Flowable`.